# Split a text file at where a string occurs using Python 2.7

Tags: python, python-2.x

Using Python, how do you split a text file right at the position where a particular string occurs?

I tried using `.split()` but it gave an error: `AttributeError: 'file' object has no attribute 'split'`

**Code:**

```
book = open('finn.txt')
x = book.split('*** START OF THIS PROJECT GUTENBERG EBOOK HUCKLEBERRY FINN ***')
```

**File: finn.txt**

```
Title: Adventures of Huckleberry Finn, Complete

Author: Mark Twain (Samuel Clemens)


*** START OF THIS PROJECT GUTENBERG EBOOK HUCKLEBERRY FINN ***

Produced by David Widger
```

**Desired Output**

```
Produced by David Widger
```

Comment: `book` is file object.  You need to read the data:  `book = open('finn.txt').read()`, for example.

Comment: Is it such a bad question to deserve downvotes?

Comment: I didn't think it deserved a downvote.  But I suppose "but it didn't work" wasn't as helpful as it could have been ;-)  That is, would have helped a lot more to spell out exactly what "didn't work" meant.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `read()` to read the entire file into a string

Then use `split(...)[1]` to get the part after your marker

```
book = open('finn.txt').read()
x = book.split('*** START OF THIS PROJECT GUTENBERG EBOOK HUCKLEBERRY FINN ***')[1]
```